# LinkedHashMap issue... Anyone help me out

Tags: groovy

While executing this test case, following error I'm facing...
Please anyone suggests me in overcoming this issue.

```
AbortedJobImportTest 


testAbortedJobAddedSuccessfullyToExcludedRun    


Unknown entity: java.util.LinkedHashMap 
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.util.LinkedHashMap
    at com.rsa.test.crawler.CrawlerTestBase.setUp(CrawlerTestBase.groovy:42)
    at com.rsa.test.crawler.AbortedJobImportTest.setUp(AbortedJobImportTest.groovy:19)
```

/*
        ***

```
CrawlerTestBase

    public class CrawlerTestBase extends GroovyTestCase {
        static transactional = false;
        def productsModel;
        protected JenkinsJobCrawlerDTO jenkinsCrawlerDTO;
        def jenkinsJobService; 
        def httpClientService;
        def sessionFactory;
        def productModelsService;
        protected String JENKINS_URL = "http://10.101.43.253:8080/jenkins/";
        protected String JENKINS_JOB_CONSTANT= "job";
        protected String JUNIT_TEST_PARAMETERS = "type=junit";
        protected String CUSTOM_JUNIT_SELENIUM_TEST_PARAMETERS = "type=selenium,outputfile=Custom-junit-report*";
        protected String DEFAULT_PRODUCT = "AM";

        public void setUp(){
            deleteDataFromTables();
            Date date = new Date();

            productsModel = new ProductModel(product:DEFAULT_PRODUCT,jenkinsServers:"10.101.43.253",date:date);
            if (productsModel.validate()) {
                productsModel.save(flush:true);
                log.info("Added entry for prodct model for "+DEFAULT_PRODUCT);
            }
            else {
                productsModel.errors.allErrors.each { log.error it }
            }
            jenkinsCrawlerDTO = new JenkinsJobCrawlerDTO();
            productModelsService.reinitialise();
            sessionFactory.currentSession.save(flush:true);
            sessionFactory.currentSession.clear();
        }

        public void tearDown(){
            deleteDataFromTables();
        }

        protected void deleteDataFromTables(){
            Set<String> tablesToDeleteData = new HashSet<String>();
            tablesToDeleteData.add("ExcludedJenkinsRuns");
            tablesToDeleteData.add("TestRuns");
            tablesToDeleteData.add("ProductModel");
            tablesToDeleteData.add("SystemEvents");
            tablesToDeleteData.add("JenkinsJobsToCrawl");
            tablesToDeleteData.add("TestSuitesInViewList");
            tablesToDeleteData.add("JenkinsJobsToCrawl");
            (ApplicationHolder.application.getArtefacts("Domain") as List).each {
                  if(tablesToDeleteData.contains(it.getName())){
                      log.info("Deleting data from ${it.getName()}");
                      it.newInstance().list()*.delete()  
                  }

            }
            sessionFactory.currentSession.flush();
            sessionFactory.currentSession.clear();
        }

        public void oneTimeSetUp(){

        }

        public void oneTimeTearDown(){

        }
    }
```

AbortedJobImportTest

```
        public class AbortedJobImportTest extends CrawlerTestBase {
        private String jobUrl = JENKINS_URL+JENKINS_JOB_CONSTANT+"/am-java-source-build/69/";

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
            super.setUp();
            jenkinsCrawlerDTO.setJobUrl(jobUrl);
        }

        @After
        public void cleanup() {
            super.tearDown();
        }

        @Test
        public void testAbortedJobAddedSuccessfullyToExcludedRun() {
            int countBeforeImport = ExcludedJenkinsRuns.count();
            jenkinsJobService.handleTestResults(jobUrl,JUNIT_TEST_PARAMETERS);
            int countAfterImport = ExcludedJenkinsRuns.count();
            Assert.assertEquals(countBeforeImport+1, countAfterImport);
            ExcludedJenkinsRuns excludedRun = ExcludedJenkinsRuns.findByJobNameLike(jenkinsCrawlerDTO.jobName);
            Assert.assertNotNull(excludedRun);
            Assert.assertEquals(jobUrl, excludedRun.jobUrl);
            Assert.assertEquals(jenkinsCrawlerDTO.jobName, excludedRun.jobName);
            Assert.assertEquals(jenkinsCrawlerDTO.jenkinsServer, excludedRun.jenkinsServer);
            Assert.assertEquals(jenkinsCrawlerDTO.buildNumber.toInteger(), excludedRun.buildNumber);
            Assert.assertEquals("Build Aborted", excludedRun.exclusionReason);
        }

    }
*/
```

I cant figure out the issue in this code. Can anyone help me? 
    While executing this test case, following error I'm facing...
Please anyone suggests me in overcoming this issue.

Comment: What is the line 42? Is it productsModel = new ProductModel... ? How does your ProductModel look like?

Comment: Ya its productsModel = new ProductModel(product:DEFAULT_PRODUCT,jenkinsServers:"10.101.43.253",date:date).

Comment: class ProductModel {
 static mapping = {
  table "products_model"
  id column: "id"
  product column: "product"
  jenkinsServers  column: "jenkins_servers"
  date column: "date"
  version false
  cache true
 }
 
 int id;
 String product;
 String jenkinsServers;
 Date date;

}

Comment: at first glance i thought this is grails, but it's not, right?  your ProductModel class there gets some ctor generated that takes some hibernate entitiy, but you pass it a map. if this guess is far off, please provide further informations, what libs/frameworks/... are used here, since this is not "just" a groovy problem.

Comment: framework is grails.

Comment: I think in order to pass the parameters to the constructor as a map they need to be in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you try to put a LinkedHashMap in constructor of Product Model but there is no constructor with LinkedHashMap parameter.

I guess the problem is your Unit Test. The Model constructor will be added by grails framework. You aren`t running grails framework in your Unit Test, because you use GroovyTestCase instead of Spock.
Lock here https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.5/guide/single.html#unitTesting